# socket.io, operations that takes advantage of storage backends?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I "found" that socket.io can be configured to use different storages for client storage logic, for example the [redis store](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#server) ,

my question is, what operations affect the use of that storage?

for example do an operation like socket.set('data', takes advantages of that configured storage?

what other operations?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store is used to store all data that is related to a client connections. When a connection is closed a client store [is destroyed after a expiration period](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9/lib/manager.js#L544).

As for your question related to *socket.set* the answer is: [yes, it does](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9/lib/socket.js#L247).

For an example ([taken from the socket.io website](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)) see below:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('set nickname', function (name) {
        socket.set('nickname', name, function () {
            socket.emit('ready');
        });
    });

    socket.on('msg', function () {
        socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
            console.log('Chat message by ', name);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: so for example if I have a socket and do socket.member = value, is that member saved to the store as part of socket data?

Comment: No, but you can call _socket.set(key, value, cb)_ to store data that is associated with a client's socket connection. I will add an example [from the socket.io website](http://socket.io/#how-to-use) to the answer.